# Why has this "details" accordion appeared in this view?

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that uses the table format and the "group by" setting.

I've just updated to the Drupal 8.9. Suddenly, each group has this empty *Details* accordion.

> [image: screenshot]

It wasn't there before.

Why did it appear? How can I get rid of it, other than removing it with CSS?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you try unselecting _Use rendered output to group rows_?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't remove the "details" (and in any case I need it selected, for my view to work as designed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue with a View as well. Fortunately, this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3149930) was reported to Drupal Core, fixed and released in Drupal 8.9.2 and Drupal 9.0.2 all in under a month which is quite commendable.

I just tested this issue by upgrading a test to Drupal 8.9.2 which resolved this issue.